CANape integration with .net
I want to integrate a .net application with CANAPE where I can load the cna file, add the data to calibration and measurement then save it to the MDF file, but I am getting a COM Exception while loading cna file through the tool.
Can anyone guide me in this?
I tried loading the file using the below
Mapp = new CANAPELib.Application() as IApplication2;
Mapp.LoadCNAFile(filename);

But got a DISP_E_EXCEPTION
